# How to add array by hidden type in cake php?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I want to carry an array from one form to another form by hidden data type in cake php.
I don't know how many number will come. So, I can not know how many number.
e.g.

Example in PHP:

```
foreach($rNo as $no){
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='no[".$no."]' value='".$no."'>";
}
```

How do I translate this code to CakePHP `$form->hidden()`?

Answer (score 2):

Serialize the array and store it.

Comment: Cant it be stored as a string in a single hidden field?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the OP's question. He's asking how to effectively use the cakePHP helper function `$form->hidden()` to produce the equivalent php code he posted above.

Comment: Other form is not know how many number will carry from this from. That's why, I want to carry array by hidden type.

Comment: why -1? It's the only way to put an array in one field. It makes a string that can put in the value field of the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

For hidden input types you just use

`$form->input('Model.field', array('type' => 'hidden'));`

In your controller you just set the data eg `$this->data['Model']['field'] = 'value';`

For multiple fields you could loop through the $this->data array.

Your this->data would look like `$this->data['Model'][0]['field'], $this->data['Model'][1]['field']`

```
foreach($this->data['Model'] as $key => $data){
    $form->input('Model.'.$key.'.field', array('type' => 'hidden'));
}
```

It doesn't have to be $this->data, you could use any variable. But $this->data would automatically fill the input fields.

But you could just pass the value too if you wanted to. `$form->input('Model.field', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 'myvalue'));`

Comment: You can save it in a session, eg: $this->Session->write('MyData', 'youdata');, and retrieve it $this->Session->read('MyData');